# localhost in sudoers

Tags: unix, permissions, sudo, localhost, sudoers

There is no chance of an internal attack, so I would like to give sudo privileges to users at the local computer using **sudoers**. I tried these lines separately:

```
%admin localhost=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%admin 127.0.0.1=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But sudoers does not seem recognize either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Is there an alternative, and if so, how secure would it be? Could a remote attacker gain local user privileges using **cron** or some other method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

The host list restricts the sudo rule to hosts on which one network interface has a name or address in the list. Since every host has a loopback interface, every host should match your rule; in fact, sudo skips the loopback interface when checking host lists, so no host does match your rule; either way specifying the host as `localhost` is not useful.

Sudo doesn't do any network authentication: the host list is there so that you can deploy a single `sudoers` file on multiple machines and give users different permissions on different machines.

Cron also doesn't do any network authentication. A remote user would gain user privileges through a misconfigured or vulnerable network server or client (http, ftp, samba, nfs, snmp, ssh, …).

Comment: "Since every host has a loopback interface, every host matches your rule."
Are you sure that's correct? Neither `localhost` nor `127.0.0.1` seem to match the local computer.

Comment: @Josh: that's the documented behavior. In fact sudo skips the loopback interface when checking whether the host is in the list. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Either way, specifying `localhost` in the host list is not useful.

Comment: Every host *would* match your rule, if the sudo system allowed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your hostname is not a "localhost".
See output `hostname` command or check content your /etc/hostname

Comment: How is hostname going to help ? Can you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

sudo does not know anything about the loopback interface (localhost/127.0.0.1), but it knows about all of the other interfaces. If your machine has *at least* one such interface, then it is considered to be on a network. Thus during the interface configuration -generally done during the OS installation- you were required to set a "host name", or maybe one was assigned automatically.

This "host name" can be accessed via the "hostname" command or the /etc/hostname file.

As a consequence,
(i) your machine has a loopback interface but also certainly a "host name"
(ii) sudo can only use this "network name"
(iii) if you replace "localhost=" by "<your hostname>" in your sudoers file, the rule will match and everything will work as you expect.